# Confused about Spring boot test specific @TestConfiguration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-test-mvc, spring-boot-test

According to [Spring Boot Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M7/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config), a nested `@TestConfiguration` should be detected by tests automatically.

But in my test codes it is problematic when I ran the whole test class, it was not detected even I added it explicitly by `@Import`. The test code structure is like the following:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
//@Import(IntegrationTests.TestSecurityConfig.class)
public class IntegrationTests {

// test methods

   // test configuration
   @TestConfiguration
   static class TestSecurityConfig {}

}
```

**When I ran single test cases(test methods) individually, all tests are passed as expected**, but when I ran the test class directly, some tests are failed, the `@TestConfiguration` was not applied to test.

The complete codes of this `IntegrationTests` is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-microservice-sample/blob/master/post-service/src/test/java/com/hantsylabs/sample/springmicroservice/post/IntegrationTests.java).

**UPDATE**:
A workaround added in my codes to make the tests passed.

```
@TestComponent
@Slf4j
static class TestUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    TestUserDetailsService(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserDetails user = User.withUsername("user")
            .password(passwordEncoder.encode("password"))
            .roles("USER")
            .accountExpired(false)
            .accountLocked(false)
            .credentialsExpired(false)
            .disabled(false)
            .build();

        UserDetails admin = User.withUsername("admin")
            .password(passwordEncoder.encode("password"))
            .roles("ADMIN")
            .accountExpired(false)
            .accountLocked(false)
            .credentialsExpired(false)
            .disabled(false)
            .build();

        log.debug("dummy user:" + user);
        log.debug("dummy admin:" + admin);


        if ("user".equals(username)) {
            return user;
        } else {
            return admin;
        }
    }
}

@TestConfiguration
@Slf4j
@Import(TestUserDetailsService.class)
@Order(-1)
static class TestSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Inject
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/posts/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/posts/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

}

There are still some things confused me.

1. In the test class, why the `@TestConfiguration` can not detect `@TestComponent` located in the same test, I  have to add `@Import` to fix it.
2. As described in the [security section of Spring Boot Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M7/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security), I was thinking defining a `UserDetailsService` bean is enough, it will serve the users in security, but it did not work in tests. I have to configure a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and expose `AuthenticationManager` for test, why? And more confused me is as described before , running the tests one by one is ok if there is no `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` defined for test.
3. The `@TestConfiguration` annotated `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` does not get a higer order, I have to add `@Order` on it. I was thinking a  `@TestConfiguration` bean should get Primary automatically and replace the bean in my application config, right?

Comment: It should work if you put the Config class outside of your test class. Any reason you need it all in the one class?

Comment: @Dovmo Tried to move out of test class, got the same result.

Comment: @Dovmo This may be a specific issue when loading application context of the SpringSecuirty, in [another test](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-microservice-sample/blob/master/post-service/src/test/java/com/hantsylabs/sample/springmicroservice/post/PostServiceTest.java), `TestConfiguration` works.

Comment: Had a problem when `@TestConfiguration` applied to late. By that time another component with `@ConditionalOnBean` had already been skipped.
Using `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` helped.

Comment: @leonid `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` worked perfectly for my issue of `@TestConfiguration` processing after my `@ConditionalOnBean`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` solved it in my case:

```java
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@TestConfiguration
```

I'm not quite sure why that isn't the default. My `@ConditionalOnBean` was evaluated before that `@TestConfiguration` was actually initializing those beans.